# How does cd command work? (unix)

Tags: unix-shell, command-line-interface

Could anybody explain to me how `cd -` command work? man cd tells me that `An argument of - is equivalent to $OLDPWD.` Then I found on the net that $OLDPWD is the previous working directory as set by the cd command. And when I do cd - on my unix I get `-bash: cd: OLDPWD not set` which is confusing for me.

**UPDATE:** it works now it gives me the previous working directory. I guess I did not use and cd command before so that is why $OLDPWD was not set.

One more question what `cd` (type cd and press enter) does? I wouldn't say that nothing. Is there any better technical explanation?

```
host [~]# cd
host [~]#
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`OLDPWD` is not set, because you have't changed directory

```
[dave@odessa ~]$ cd -
-bash: cd: OLDPWD not set
[dave@odessa ~]$ cd /tmp
[dave@odessa tmp]$ cd -
/export/home/dave

[dave@odessa ~]$ cd /tmp
[dave@odessa tmp]$ echo $OLDPWD
/export/home/dave
```

`cd` without any arguments will `chdir` to `$HOME`

```
[dave@odessa tmp]$ echo $HOME
/export/home/dave
[dave@odessa tmp]$ HOME=/ cd
[dave@odessa /]$ pwd
/
```

Comment: @Dave Cheney: thank you Dave, great answer. Crystal clear now ...

Answer (score 6):

```
type cd
```

tells us that

> cd is a shell builtin

```
man sh
```

tells us what you found out:

> If a single dash is specified as the argument, it will be replaced by the value of OLDPWD.

The internal implementation of cd in the shell does a [chdir(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/chdir) -syscall.

Comment: @ptman: looks like we are having different results with different shells in both `cd -` and `cd` cases

Comment: Nice, I never knew about `type`. I was used to man _(some shell builtin)_ giving me the raspberry.

Answer (score 1):

`cd` by itself changes to your home directory

```
$ cd /tmp
$ pwd
/tmp
$ cd
$ pwd
/home/username
```

Comment: @Dennis Williamson: yes, yes, I already forgot ...